# Material that Changes States with Electricity Passing Through It?

Tags: electricity, states-of-matter

Is there a material out there that can change it's state (gas/liquid/solid) depending on the electric field induced within it?

Comment: You can certainly [ionise a gas to a plasma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_discharge_in_gases) with am applied voltage. I don’t know of a liquid-gas or solid-liquid transion being induced that way off the top of my head, but I does not seem obviously impossible

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to that would be an *electrorheological fluid* or ER fluid. If you apply an electric field across a sample of ER fluid, its viscosity suddenly increases and stays that way until the voltage is shut off.

You can make a mechanical clutch with no moving parts except the clutch plates by filling the space between them with ER fluid. When you turn on the voltage, the viscosity increase essentially locks the plates together and the clutch transmits power. Some early models of Honda SUV's used ER clutches to shift from 2-wheel drive to 4-wheel drive.